# Command to convert an upper-case string to lower-case?

Tags: bash, scripts

What is the Bash command I can use to convert an upper-case string to lower-case and vice-versa?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible same as: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51983/bash-how-to-uppercase-the-command-line-argument

Comment: Lots of solutions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting too. With a cursory glance most seem to be covered here as well.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If the string is already stored in a variable you can use `bash`'s parameter expansion, specifially `${parameter,,pattern}` (available since bash 4.0), where `parameter` is the name of your variable and `pattern` is ommitted:

```
$ string="Hello, World!"
$ echo $string
Hello, World!
$ echo ${string,,}
hello, world!
```

Note that this does not change the value of the variable, only the output. To change the variable you have to assign the new value:

```
$ echo $string
Hello, World!
$ string=${string,,}
$ echo $string
hello, world!
```

The upper-case conversion works with `${parameter^^pattern}`:

```
$ echo ${string^^}
HELLO, WORLD!
```

This works also with Unicode strings (at least with current bash versions, probably needs at least bash 4.3):

```
$ string='ἈΛΦΆβητος'
$ echo ${string,,}
ἀλφάβητος
$ echo ${string^^}
ἈΛΦΆΒΗΤΟΣ
```

---

If you are using `zsh`, you can use *Parameter Expansion Flags* (`${(FLAGS)NAME}`; available since zsh 2.5) to achieve the same results. The `bash` syntax does not work in `zsh` <sup>1)</sup>. The flag for lower case is `L`; for upper case it is `U`:

```
$ string="Hello, World!"
$ echo ${(L)string}
hello, world!
$ echo ${(U)string}
HELLO, WORLD!
$ echo $string
Hello, World!"
```

This also works with Unicode strings (at least since zsh 5.0; I did not try with earlier versions):

```
$ string='ἈΛΦΆβητος'
$ echo ${(L)string} 
ἀλφάβητος
$ echo ${(U)string}  
ἈΛΦΆΒΗΤΟΣ
```

---

---

<sup>1)</sup> Although, seeing that zsh had this for far longer, it should probably be: *"the `zsh` syntax does not work in `bash`*.

Comment: The `${string,,}` notation only exists for bash version 4+. Otherwise one of the other solutions is required, such as `$(echo $string | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')`.

Answer (score 40):

There are very few methods that work correctly with Unicode:

GNU sed 4.2.2 **works**:

```
$ echo "Idą gęsi łąką" | sed 's/.*/\U&/'
IDĄ GĘSI ŁĄKĄ
```

---

bash 4.2.45 declare does **not** work:

```
$ typeset -u ucase; ucase="Idą gęsi łąką"; echo $ucase
IDą GęSI łąKą
```

bash 4.2.45 parameter expansion does **not** work:

```
$ str="Idą gęsi łąką"; echo ${str^^}
IDą GęSI łąKą
```

bash 4.3.42 `declare` and parameter expansion **work**:

```
$ declare -u ucase
$ ucase="Idą gęsi łąką"
$ echo $ucase
IDĄ GĘSI ŁĄKĄ
$ echo ${ucase,,}
idą gęsi łąką
```

---

GNU tr 8.20 does **not** work:

```
$ echo "Idą gęsi łąką" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
IDą GęSI łąKą
```

---

mawk (default awk in Ubuntu 13.10) does **not** work:

```
$ echo "Idą gęsi łąką" | mawk '{print toupper($0)}'
IDą GęSI łąKą
```

---

gawk **works**:

```
$ echo "Idą gęsi łąką" | gawk '{print toupper($0)}'
IDĄ GĘSI ŁĄKĄ
```

---

Perl pure uc() does **not** work:

```
$ echo "Idą gęsi łąką" | perl -ne 'print uc($_);'
IDą GęSI łąKą
```

---

Python 2 without any Unicode hints does **not** work:

```
$ echo "Idą gęsi łąką" | python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdin.read().upper(),'
IDą GęSI łąKą
```

Python 2 when instructed to deal with Unicode **works**:

```
$ echo "Idą gęsi łąką" | python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdin.read().decode("utf-8").upper(),'
IDĄ GĘSI ŁĄKĄ
```

---

Python 3 **works**:

```
$ echo "Idą gęsi łąką" | python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().upper(), end="")'
IDĄ GĘSI ŁĄKĄ
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.04, I have `gawk` as the default awk (as shown with `update-alternatives --display awk`). Are you sure `mawk` is the default in 13.10?

Comment: `sed`s since 1990 have supported the `\U` option ;-). Not a gnu-sed specific feature. Otherwise, great answer, so many options, so little time ;-) Good luck to all!

Comment: Plus there will be some issues with Turkish (dotted and dotless i), for more look at the following links:
- http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/SpecialCasing.txt
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524231/lower-case-of-turkish-character-dotted-i
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

Comment: In your example, purse `uc` doesn't work in Perl because you have to `use Encode` or  `use utf8`. Rewrite your example as  `echo "Idą gęsi łąką" | perl -ne 'use Encode;print encode("utf-8",uc(decode("utf-8",$_)))'` and it will work. Also see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13261662/3701431

Comment: @shellter – FreeBSD 11.2 `sed` does not support `\U`. It gives you a literal `U`, e.g. `UIdą gęsi łąką`. Also of note: FreeBSD 11.2 `tr` works, GNU Coreutils 8.32 `tr` still fails.

Answer (score 21):

I would use the bash internal **typeset** or **declare** command to define a lowercase variable.

```
$ typeset -l lcase
$ lcase="LoWeR cAsE"
$ echo $lcase
lower case
```

The chars are lowered when the value is set, not when you typeset the variable. So it is better to typeset at the beginning of the script. For uppercase you can **typeset -u**.

```
$ typeset -u ucase
$ ucase="Upper cAsE"
$ echo $ucase
UPPER CASE
```

*This is not specific to bash shell, that works also on ksh, maybe its in POSIX shell definition.*

EDIT: 
Many people gently pointed me the fact that **typeset** is now considered obsolete on bash and replaced by **declare**. Both commands are equivalent.

```
$ help typeset
typeset: typeset [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] name[=value] ...
    Set variable values and attributes.

    Obsolete.  See `help declare'.


$ help declare
declare: declare [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
    Set variable values and attributes.
```

*I myself still use the typeset syntax as I work on heterogeneous environment, so I have not to rewrite my scripts.*

Comment: +1 Incredible, i never knew that one !  b.t.w. some extra info:  I looked this up in the manual and it seems that `typeset` is considered depricated and replaced by `declare`

Comment: @thom thank you, it seems that bash started to have a life far from its "bourne shell roots"  :)

Answer (score 18):

You can do it with the `tr` command.

In the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

This command:

```
echo 'String here' | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]"
```

will convert lowercase to uppercase.

```
echo 'STRING HERE' | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"
```

will convert uppercase to lowercase.

Example:

[image]

Credit goes to [cybercity](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-linux-unix-tr-command/)

Comment: If you don't care about locales, `tr A-Z a-z` will work as well.

Comment: For Unicode, this works in BSD (tested in FreeBSD 11.2) but _not_ in GNU coreutils (8.32). See [Michał Šrajer's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/383819/260416) and [my comment](https://askubuntu.com/q/383352/260416#comment2350658_383819) below it.

Answer (score 10):

You can pipe things through `sed` too:

```
$ echo lowercase | sed 's/.*/\U&/'
LOWERCASE
```

And `\L` will have the opposite effect:

```
$ echo UPPERCASE | sed 's/.*/\L&/'
uppercase
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a pure bash solution, but you can pipe your strings through `perl` (as  [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) did with `sed`):

```
$ echo lowercase | perl -ne 'print "\U$_"'
LOWERCASE
```

And `\L` will have the opposite effect:

```
$ echo UPPERCASE | perl -ne 'print "\L$_"'
uppercase
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this simple command
For upper to lower case
Where 'f' is file name where you want to do conversion.

```
tr "A-Z" "a-z" < f
```

For lower to upper case

```
tr "a-z" "A-Z" < f
```

Comment: As noted [in a comment on an older answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/383352/command-to-convert-an-upper-case-string-to-lower-case/536774#comment489585_383356), this won't work for some locales.